# Why is the textbox getting hidden?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code

```
<td class="tr-black" ng-bind="func(x.md,'monthly_inactive')" width="45%" class="text-center">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"  id="monthly_inactive" name="monthly_inactive" class="form-control floating month" value="{{ x.monthly_rec }}"  onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber(event)">
    <label class="floating" for="monthly_inactive">Monthly</label>
</div>
```

//angularjs code, values in d and p are correct.

```
$scope.func = function(d, p) {
  console.log("d: " + d + "\np: " + p);
  $('#' + p).focus();
  if (d == "Y") {
    $('#' + p).attr('readonly', true);
  } else {
    $('#' + p).attr('readonly', false);
  }
}
```

When I load the page I am not getting the text box.

Answer (score 0):

`ngBind` directive replaces the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression. In your case, the content inside `td` is replaced with `ng-bind` expression value that is the return value of `func(x.md,'monthly_inactive')`.

See doc of [ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind).